# No service package in Cobertura report

Tags: java, junit, cobertura

I have run Cobertura report, but I couldn't see my service package in the report *(index.html)*. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is service package is in the same base path?

Comment: test{
 jvmArgs '-noverify'
        include 'com/cox/fraudmanagement/service/**'
 }                                     -->this is the package where i wrote my test class . and in the report i should get a service package which is not being shown